# Get HTML document from Xamarin Forms WebView

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.webview

I am trying to get the contents of the webview as a standard HTML string, but the result is an encoded string that I can't seem to un-encode.  Here's a simple sample to illustrate:

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="TestWebView.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView Source="https://www.microsoft.com" Navigated="WebView_Navigated" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
        async void WebView_Navigated(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var webView = sender as WebView;
            var html = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(html);
        }
```

Here are the first few lines of output:

```
<html lang=\"en-us\" dir=\"ltr\" class=\"exp-4694 exp-4694T3 js exp-4065 exp-4065T1\"><head data-info=\"{&quot;v&quot;:&quot;1.0.7502.2744&quot;,&quot;a&quot;:&quot;1d1b0ad9-2b52-4c52-a443-3cb3a1c98a83&quot;,&quot;cn&quot;:&quot;OneDeployContainer&quot;,&quot;az&quot;:&quot;{did:92e7dc58ca2143cfb2c818b047cc5cd1, rid: OneDeployContainer, sn: marketingsites-prod-odeastus, dt: 2018-05-03T20:14:23.4188992Z, bt: 2020-07-16T09:31:28.0000000Z}&quot;,&quot;ddpi&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;dpio&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;dpi&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;dg&quot;:&quot;uplevel.web.mobile.webkit.ios&quot;,&quot;th&quot;:&quot;default&quot;,&quot;m&quot;:&quot;en-us&quot;,&quot;l&quot;:&quot;en-us&quot;,&quot;mu&quot;:&quot;en-us&quot;,&quot;rp&quot;:&quot;/en-us/&quot;,&quot;f&quot;:&quot;sfwaaa,atperf680t2,5583t1,enablebuynowctrl,5355t1,3857t1,4694t2,3286t1,tasmigration010,cartemberpl,disablenorefunds,daconvertenabled,myflightcf&quot;,&quot;bh&quot;:{}}\" class=\"at-element-marker\">\n        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
```

In other webviews (like Plugin.HybridWebView), the results come out as expected.  I'm trying to find a way to use the "official" webview since most of these others are no longer maintained.

How can I unencode/unescape this string or prevent the webview from encoding it in the first place?

Comment: This is because of coding format . You could decode the html string by `WebUtility.HtmlDecode(html);`

Comment: Thanks @LucasZhang-MSFT.  That gets it close, but all of the string literals are double-escaped.  For example, the strings show up as "\\\"" instead of "\"".  I can do a replace on that, but I don't think that's very safe.  Thoughts?

Comment: You could convert the string again manually by using Regular Expression .

Comment: Thanks for your help, Lucas.  As I continue to work through this, I'm finding more issues with this non-standard implementation of WebView.EvaluateJavascriptAsync(), such as getting an EOF error when passing perfectly formed JS.  The same code works in Flutter and in other 3rd party Xamarin webview implementations, but not in Xamarin's WebView.  I will log this as a bug with Xamarin.

Comment: Does it work now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a user named "jgold6" on the GitHub bug report for this issue, he suggested the following:

```
// fetch the document element
var page = await controller.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");

// Unescape that damn Unicode Java bull.
page = Regex.Replace(page, @"\\[Uu]([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})", m => char.ToString((char)ushort.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)));
page = Regex.Unescape(page);
```

This effectively solved the problem for me.  This is also what Lucas suggested above.  Thanks all for the help on this.

Comment: Spent all evening trying to get HtmlAgilityPack and the Html from my WebView to play ball and kept returning no elements when trying to SelectNodes or FindElements. I thought my issue would be down to some encoding! Strange this is the only question/answer that touches on it!

Answer (score 1):

Actually Xamarin.Forms is returning whatever the native platform is returning as designed, and what the platform returned is Escaped html, the 3rd party WebView(Plugin.HybridWebView ) is doing extra things to unescape the html like stripping out the extraneous stuff: `'', '"' ...`

As a workaround , we could  get the html without any escaped quotes by invoke the following lines

```
private async void WebView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var webView = sender as WebView;
            // instead of getting the html with the EvaluateJavaScriptAsync method
            //var html = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML");

            // they can get it with an HttpClient:
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync((webView.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url);
        }
```

Comment: The disadvantage to that approach is that we are fetching the page twice.

Comment: We can also say that cookies are lost or not shared